# Get focus for JTextField in JFileChooser (NimbusLookAndFeel)

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser, nimbus

By default, a `JFileChooser` in `NimbusLookAndFeel` doesn't show focus on the `JTextField` where the user types the file path. The focus owner in `JFileChooser` is the `JComboBox` as show in the figure.

[image: Screenshot of the JFileChooser (NimbusLookAndFeel)]

Now how could i get the focus for the `JTextField` when the user opens the `JFileChooser`. I tried doing `requestFocusInWindow()` on the `JTextField` by getting it from the `JFileChooser` through recursive logic. Here is the full code that i have done.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
class GetFocusForJTextField extends JFrame
{
JButton jb;
JFileChooser jf;

    public GetFocusForJTextField()
    {
        createAndShowGUI();
    }

    private void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        // For NimbusLookAndFeel, JTextField is not
        // the default focus owner in JFileChooser
        try
        {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel("javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
        }catch(Exception e){}

        setTitle("Get Focus for JTextField");
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        setSize(400,400);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jb=new JButton("Open JFileChooser");
        jb.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
            {
                showDialog();
            }
        });

        jf=new JFileChooser();

        add(jb);
    }

    // Loop to find the JTextField, the first
    // JTextField in JFileChooser
    private void grabFocusForTextField(Component[] c)
    {
        for(Component k:c)
        {
            if(k instanceof JTextField)
            {
                JTextField jt=(JTextField)k;
                jt.requestFocusInWindow();
                break;
            }
            else if(k instanceof JPanel)
            {
                JPanel jp=(JPanel)k;
                grabFocusForTextField(jp.getComponents());
            }
        }
    }

    private void showDialog()
    {
        jf.showOpenDialog(this);
        grabFocusForTextField(jf.getComponents());
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run()
            {
                new GetFocusForJTextField();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Still i am unable to get the focus. Why am i not getting this.

Comment: please only Nimbus caused this issue or SystemL&F too

Comment: The problem is lying only in the `NimbusLookAndFeel`. I tested on `WindowsLookAndFeel`, `WindowsClassicLookAndFeel` and `MetalLookAndFeel` and also `MotifLookAndFeel`

Comment: I think that I post set focus with value once (or a few times here???), can I search or you will do that (use always tag inside`[`tag`]`, otherwise you lost majority of threads == crazy engine on 1st. sight:-)

Comment: I've searched for about 2 minutes. If you find it, i will delete it. No problem :) Thanks.

Comment: didn't see added image, are you meaning paint focus around JComboBox with selected Item with value `My Document` ???

Comment: +1 good catch :-) Technical reason is that SynthFileChooserUI _is_ listening to the ancestor property of the fileChooser and delegates to an internal method `doAncestorChange(..)` which is ... empty. My learn item today, plus the fact that `JComponent.addNotify()` fires a propertyChange

Comment: again my question -> Focus is about JComboBox or JTextField,

Comment: you probably to love Nimbus so much, then is time time to use custom L&Fs based on Nimbus, or (solved in custom L&F) reload initial keys with own xml file, [you can start with idea by @aephyr](http://aephyr.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/), long time that I tried, his violet (or pink) color sc(T)heme

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing here is upon call to the `grabFocusForTextField()` the `JTextField` is not **displayable** as a result you cannot get the focus for the `JTextField`. For a component to get a focus, the component must exist first, visible and displayable, enabled and focusable. See the [Focus subsystem in docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html) for more.

You will have to register your own `HierarchyListener` on the `JFileChooser` to listen to `HierarchyEvent`. In the `NimbusLookAndFeel` either this might not be done properly or the `JComboBox` was chosen to be the focus owner. Whenever the component is displayable, whenever the `JFileChooser`'s hierarchy is changed, this event is fired and at that time, the `JTextField` is displayable.

I have rewritten the code to make this work.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
class GetFocusForJTextField extends JFrame
{
JButton jb;
JFileChooser jf;

    public GetFocusForJTextField()
    {
        createAndShowGUI();
    }

    private void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        // For NimbusLookAndFeel, JTextField is not
        // the default focus owner in JFileChooser
        try
        {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel("javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
        }catch(Exception e){}

        setTitle("Get Focus for JTextField");
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        setSize(400,400);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jb=new JButton("Open JFileChooser");
        jb.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
            {
                showDialog();
            }
        });

        jf=new JFileChooser();

        // Even if you add some other JTextField
        // as accessory to JFileChooser
        jf.setAccessory(new JTextField(20));

        jf.addHierarchyListener(new HierarchyListener(){
            public void hierarchyChanged(HierarchyEvent he)
            {
                grabFocusForTextField(jf.getComponents());
            }
        });     

        add(jb);
    }

    // Loop to find the JTextField, the first
    // JTextField in JFileChooser
    // Even if you setAccessory which contains a JTextField
    // or which is JTextField itself, it will not get focus
    private void grabFocusForTextField(Component[] c)
    {
        for(Component k:c)
        {
            if(k instanceof JTextField)
            {
                JTextField jt=(JTextField)k;
                jt.grabFocus();
                break;
            }
            else if(k instanceof JPanel)
            {
                JPanel jp=(JPanel)k;
                grabFocusForTextField(jp.getComponents());
            }
        }
    }

    private void showDialog()
    {
        jf.showOpenDialog(this);
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run()
            {
                new GetFocusForJTextField();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

You can also use `requestFocusInWindow()` instead of `grabFocus()`

Comment: Focus is simple asynchronous, required to wrap into invokeLater, especially for containers based on JDialog, JDialog without parent

Comment: @mKorbel asynch or not - not focusing the textfield is simply a bug in SynthFileChooserUI

Comment: Hmm. That sounds good, focus is asynchronous but still other look and feels have focus on the `JTextField` only, this is probably a bug. +1 kleopatra

Comment: @kleopatra similair issue were solved in Metal theme (I'll search for)by @

Comment: @kleopatra blablabla only [bug in my hdd/rom this was about caret & selection, not about focus](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17103171/making-a-jfilechooser-select-the-text-of-the-file-name-but-not-the-extension)